# How does PhD candidate salary compares between differen European countries, and the USA?

Tags: phd, united-states, salary, europe, chemistry

I would like to know which is the salary average of a PhD candidate position in chemistry in different countries of Europe or in USA.

I know that in Germany and France the salaries are around 1300€ after tax and in Spain, Italy and Portugal around 900€ (correct me if I´m wrong).

Comment: In Italy the PhD scholarship depends on the university and can range from about 1000 €/month to about 1500 €/month.

Comment: @jakebeal: I suspect the OP means "net", as in "post-tax".

Comment: Related: [European Ph.D. student salary range web site (closed)](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/42869/10643)

Comment: I find this to be an OK question. Possibly a bit broad but there is nothing on our site now about this exact question, and I think well-documented answers would be useful to the community.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that the data quickly becomes stale and there's too much variance. For example, in the USA it ranges from -$40,000 (you pay the school tuition) to $30,000  (tuition waiver + full stipend). We could post 2015 data here, but it'd be useless by 2020 (which is why StackExchange as a whole shies away from this kind of thing).

Answer (score 3):

it depends on your contract.

In Germany you have a contract as TVL 13.

Fulltime netto: 2200-2400 Euro